# Trying to Print a Diamond Based on User-Determined Width in C++

Tags: c++

I'm studying for my intro to C++ midterm, and one of the review problems is trying to print a solid diamond shape using nested loops.  The user determines how wide the widest row is and what character the diamond is made from.  I know that many similar questions have already been asked, but this problem is different from any examples I've been able to find, I don't understand those examples, and I cannot seem to understand the logic of the diamond well enough to apply it to nested loops.  So, I thought I'd come here.

I worked with a tutor, and we came up with the following code:

```
    for (x = 1; x <= width; x += 2)
{
    string wSpace;
    string charSpace;

    cout << wSpace.assign(row, '#');
    cout << charSpace.assign(x, character) << endl;

    row--;
}
```

The variable `width` is a positive integer greater than 3 inputted by the user. 
 This code produces the top half of the diamond and the widest row.

The only problem with this code is that I don't know what's going on.  He used the `.assign()` function, but I don't understand what I've read about what it is or how it works.  How is it functioning here, what is it doing?  I feel like I would understand this code and problem better if I knew what the `.assign()` does.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign)?

Comment: I've been a intro to C++ student for 10 weeks, so, honestly, most of that page.  I didn't know of it before you linked to it, but I don't understand the notation for any of what I assume to be examples showing what kinds of arguments the function takes.  For example, what does "basic_string&&" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/), you'd be using fill(5).  As it says in the docs, this version of `assign()` `Replaces the current value by n consecutive copies of character c.`  In this case, `n` would be `x` or `row`, and the character would be `character` or `'#'`.  So in the first usage, you are saying `wSpace` is now a string of `'#'` characters repeated `row` times, and the second instance, you are saying `charSpace` is now a string of `character` characters repeated `x` times.